# GET webrequest parameters

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am sending a GET request to a site and would like to know what would be the proper way to do this based on the following parameters.

> Host: www.somesite
>        User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.6)    Gecko/20100625 
>        Firefox/3.6.6 GTB7.1 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0E)
>   Accept: text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*
>   Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
>   Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
>   Keep-Alive: 115
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
>   X-Prototype-Version: 1.6.1
>   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
>   Referer: http://www.somewebsite.com/search/
>   Content-Length: 19
>   Cookie: __some cookie
>   Pragma: no-cache
>   Cache-Control: no-cache

I did use firebug to get this and now am trying to create my own request header as follows:

```
        webRequest = TryCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)

        Thread.Sleep(New TimeSpan(0, 0, 10))
        'webRequest.Credentials = credentials
        webRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookielogin)

        webRequest.Method = method__1.ToString()
        webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = True
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.6) Gecko/20100625 Firefox/3.6.6 GTB7.1 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0E)"
        webRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
        webRequest.KeepAlive = True
```

my url that I have shows in firebug post header the following parameters:

```
ajax    1
page        2
q           item
```

Now I have included this in my get request since I need to retrieve multiple pages but I only get page 1 back. Am I missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this; thanks for the response.

It involved placing parameters within the body of the request.

Answer (score 0):

Get firebug, you can view the request header and set your custom request header to/from server